# How to send notification to specific user in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

I am new on Visual Studio Team Serivces, I am using it  as a Source Control, I have added some users under my team project.

I would like sometimes to send a notification to a specific User or All,  when they open their Team dashboard. How can I do this?

Comment: What sort of information do you want to notify them of? There's nothing that does what you want, but depending on the information there may be a better way of making it discoverable for them.

Answer (score 0):

VSTS supports create alerts on `https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/teamproject/_admin/_alerts`, you can set alerts for yourself or a team or a team member with:

- Work Item Alerts
- Checkin Alerts
- Build Alerts
- Code Review Alerts

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/track/alerts-and-notifications

Or you can use **[Team Room](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/productivity/collaborate-in-a-team-room)** to communicate with your team.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to control notification on the dashboard when users log in. You can have generic messages and announcements with a Wiki control.

If you want custom messages per user or group then You will need to create an extension: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/extensions/overview